# indexPathForSelectedRow on previous UITableViews always returns nil?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a stack of UITableViews managed by a UINavigationController. When I try calling indexPathForSelectedRow on any of the previous UITableViews, I always get nil:

```
NSEnumerator *e = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectEnumerator];
UITableViewController *controller;
while (controller = [e nextObject]) {
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [[controller tableView] indexPathForSelectedRow]; // always nil
    // ...
}
```

I can't find anything about this behavior in Apple's docs; is it intentional? If so, is there another way to do what I'm trying to do, without me having to resort to manually managing a redundant mySelectedIndexPath instance variable inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath or somesuch?

Comment: This should work. Maybe navigationController isn't referencing the right object. How do you get the navigationContoller into the views that you push on the stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-visible view in a `UINavigationController` stack can be unloaded at any time, therefore you can't rely on the state of non-visible views.

It's quite possible that the `UITableViewController` you're referencing would have already unloaded its table view, in which case calling `[controller tableView]` will instantiate a new view.

Comment: Interesting; thanks for the info. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: See the Memory Management section in the UIViewController documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I was noticing this as well on the iPad, in a splitscreen view (left, right detail pane), and it's kinda annoying. However, I found that if you override viewWillAppear, you can get the selected row for the table view *before* you call [super viewWillAppear];

So if you had some code like this, indexPathForSelectedRow would be nil,

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if(![_self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow])
    {
        NSLog(@"nothing selected, so selecting 1st one");
            // sets the detail pane here. 
    }
}
```

but if the code was like this (note the viewWillAppear: at the end), then indexPathForSelectedRow would not be nil.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if(![_self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow])
    {
        NSLog(@"nothing selected, so selecting 1st one");
                // sets the detail pane here. 
    }
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Comment: The only reason this seems to work is because you are using a UITableViewController and clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear defaults to YES. You should set clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear to NO and then you can access the selected row however you like without fearing that the UITableViewController will deselect it for you.